# Playback of opus-codec on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, speech, speex

I'm looking for a way to integrate opus-codec (the decoder part) with my Android application.

Do you know of any implementations that have done so? We are currently using ogg-vorbis for spoken prompts, considering going with either speex (deprecated, but with few documented attempts) or opus (currently no documented attempts).

If we would have to go the NDK route, do you think it should provide us with a application size improvement? OggVorbis is supported by the platform, neither speex nor opus are.

Comment: I am also trying to achieve similar kind of thing.Did you solve your problem?Please tell your solution.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you have a look at the [Opus API documentation](https://mf4.xiph.org/jenkins/view/opus/job/opus/ws/doc/html/index.html). Also, there's now an [OpusFile library](https://git.xiph.org/?p=opusfile.git) (equivalent to Vorbis' libvorbisfile) in early development. Otherwise, you can always read the opusdec source code.